Selecting ID that does not appear in the following months
So I am having a problem where i want to select 'ids' that stop appearing in subsequent months. I have a dataframe like:



ID
month




A
1


A
2


A
3


A
4


B
2


B
3


C
3


D
4


D
5


E
5


E
6


F
6


G
1


G
2


H
1


H
2


H
3


H
4


H
5


H
6



I am trying to select 'ids' that stop appearing in the next month, while excluding all id that appear in the last month (in this case month 6).
For example the new dataframe would be like:



ID
month




A
1


A
2


A
3


A
4


B
2


B
3


C
3


D
4


D
5


G
1


G
2



id 'E' was excluded because it appeared in month 5 and 6, id 'F' was excluded because it appeared only in the final month, and id 'H' was excluded because it appear in all months.
Possible solution:
I manage a possible solution by looping through each entry of each id and see if their last month was different from the last month in the column 'month' so i have:
last_month = df['month'].max()
for id_group in df.groupby('id'):
    id_name, group_df = id_group
    if group_df['month'].iloc[-1] != last_month:
        df_new = pd.concat([new_df, group_df], ignore_index=True)

Is there a more "elegant" way for doing this?

you say dataframe, but these are dictionaries. Are you using pandas?

Please show your atttempt. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it from scratch for you.

Do this in two steps. First get all the ids that don't appear in month 6, then get the ids that appear in all months. Then combine them.

You can try:
df[df.groupby('ID')['month'].transform('max') < df["month"].max()]


last_month = df['month'].max()
excl = df[df['month']==last_month]['ID'].values
df[df.apply(lambda r: not r['ID'] in excl,axis=1)]

